# Delphi - Lock child controls in a TPanel but with a default paint

Tags: windows, delphi, panel, message

I need to create a simple `TPanel` with some child controls (like `TEdit` or `TLabel`) but this controls must be locked!!

Locked is like a design time (with all paint events) but not clickable or focusable.
When user click on `TEdit` or `TLabel` the click mu be reflected to `TPanel`.
Also same Windows Messages must be reflected to parent (`TPanel`)

Can I do this?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Indeed, this sounds like another [XY question](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)?

Answer (score 4):

Put your controls on a TPanel and disable it.

If you want your messages (e.g. OnClick) to pass through, then put that disabled panel on another TPanel (e.g. TPanel2).  When you click any of the controls or the disabled panel, the event will fire for TPanel2.

Note: If any of your controls on the disabled panel have scroll bars (like TMemo), these will not work.